# computing intersecting of n conjuncts indirectly

Tags: elementary-set-theory

lets say you have n sets (with n > 1) and want to find intersection betwen all they, but you can only use set subtraction and set union.
[image: grapical solution]
in the figure, we have trought the diagrams that
$A\cap B=A\cup B-(A-B)\cup(B-A)$

and

$A\cap B\cap C=S-(S-A)\cup(S-B)\cup(S-C)\\
S=A\cup B\cup C-(A-B\cup C)\cup(B-A\cup C)\cup(C-A\cup B)$

could this result be extended to any higher n in sense of being possible to find the intersection of all sets using only union and subtraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (unless I misunderstand your intension).
Assume that this theorem is true in $n=k$.

Then,
\begin{equation*}
A_1\cap A_2\cap\cdots\cap A_k\cap A_{k+1}=(A_1\cap A_2\cap\cdots\cap A_k)\cap A_{k+1}=S\cap A_{k+1}\\=S\cup A_{k+1}-(S-A_{k+1})-(A_{k+1}-S).
\end{equation*}
(let $S=(A_1\cap A_2\cap\cdots\cap A_k)$)

And S can be expressed in union and substraction, we now know this theorem is true that in $n=k+1$
So, we get this theorem using induction.

Comment: i see, what would the inductive step be in that case?

Comment: I have edited now.

Comment: oh i see now, ty.